# how to solve this query using union

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Display id and name for salesmen along with id and category of products in a single table. Indicate the source of the row in result by adding an additional column TYPE with possible values as 'S' (Salesman) and 'P' (Product). Display all rows.

I don't how to add column "type" without using alter

```
select sid AS ID,sname from salesman
union
select category as "DETAILS" from product
```

actual tables are

Salesman Table

```
SID   SNAME    LOCATION
1     Peter    London
2     Michael  Paris
3     John     Mumbai
4     Harry    Chicago
5     Kevin    London
6     Alex     Chicago
```

Product Table

```
PRODID   PDESC           CATEGORY       DISCOUNT
101      Basketball      Sports         5
102      Shirt           Apparel        10
103      NULL            Electronics    15
104      CricketBat      Sports         20
105      Trouser         Apparel        5
106      Television      ELECTRONICS    20
```

expected output

```
TYPE  ID       DETAILS
P     101      Sports
P     102      Apparel
P     103      Electronics
P     104      Sports
P     105      Apparel
P     106      ELECTRONICS
```

Comment: google sql JOIN

Comment: Your expected output does not contain id and name for salesmen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want result like this?

```
TYPE ID   DETAILS
S    1    Peter
S    2    Michael
S    3    John
S    4    Harry
S    5    Kevin
S    6    Alex
P    101  Sports
P    102  Apparel
P    103  Electronics
....
```

You can try query like this

```
select 'S' AS TYPE, sid AS ID,SNAME AS DETAILS from Salesman
union
select 'P' As TYPE, PRODID, category as "DETAILS" from Product
```